# how to update kubernetes replication controller?

Tags: kubernetes

I run pods with replication controller, now i want to edit config like change value of environment and keep name of rc.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: myproject/backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: USER_ENDPOINT
          value: "http://10.0.7.29:10000"
```

For example I move service to new server and just want change value of env `USER_ENDPOINT` to `http://10.0.7.30:30100`

Now I just know follow delete rc and recreate rc, but in production i don't stop it.

I try `rolling-update` but not work because i want keep name of replication controller.

What can i do ?

Please suggest a solution, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the name of the RC?

Comment: Because I use this name for rolling-update RC with new image in follow CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kubectl edit` to edit a resource:

```
Usage:
  kubectl edit (RESOURCE/NAME | -f FILENAME) [flags]

Examples:
  # Edit the service named 'docker-registry':
  $ kubectl edit svc/docker-registry

  # Use an alternative editor
  $ KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit svc/docker-registry

  # Edit the service 'docker-registry' in JSON using the v1 API format:
  $ kubectl edit svc/docker-registry --output-version=v1 -o json
```

^^ from the kubectl help

Comment: `kubectl` in my server is version 1.0.6, it not support `edit` :))). I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially update a RC using the [HTTP PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method, like so (assuming your RC is in the `default` namespace):

```
PATCH /api/v1/namespaces/default/replicationcontrollers/backend
```

See also the [API Reference](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/api-reference/v1/operations.html).